# How can I properly use etcd Roles to control write permission on specific etcd key?

Tags: go, ssl, grpc, etcd, etcdctl

I start my etcd cluster using Go `etcd/clientv3` with following parameters:

```
"--name", "etcd-cluster"                                    
"--data-dir", "/var/lib/etcd",                      
"--wal-dir", "/var/lib",                                      
"--listen-client-urls", "127.0.0.1:2379",                        
"--listen-peer-urls", , "127.0.0.1:2380",                                                              
"--advertise-client-urls", "127.0.0.1:2379",           
"--initial-advertise-peer-urls", "127.0.0.1:2380", 
"--initial-cluster", "cluster",                          
"--initial-cluster-state", "new",                               
"--initial-cluster-token", "election",                                                             
"--cert-file", "tls.pem",                                      
"--key-file", "tls.key",                                       
"--client-cert-auth",                                           
"--trusted-ca-file", "ca.pem",                                  
"--peer-client-cert-auth",                                      
"--peer-trusted-ca-file", "peer-ca.pem",                             
"--peer-cert-file", "peer-cert.pem",                                 
"--peer-key-file", "peer.key",
```

Then I run following commands:

```
env ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=localhost:2379 --cert tls.pem --key tls.key --cacert ca.pem user add root
env ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=localhost:2379 --cert tls.pem --key tls.key --cacert ca.pem role add root
env ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=localhost:2379 --cert tls.pem --key tls.key --cacert ca.pem user add myuser
env ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=localhost:2379 --cert tls.pem --key tls.key --cacert ca.pem role add myrole
env ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=localhost:2379 --cert tls.pem --key tls.key --cacert ca.pem put /events/1 value
env ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=localhost:2379 --cert tls.pem --key tls.key --cacert ca.pem role grant-permisson myrole read /events/1
env ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=localhost:2379 --cert tls.pem --key tls.key --cacert ca.pem user grant-role root root
env ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=localhost:2379 --cert tls.pem --key tls.key --cacert ca.pem user grant-role myuser myrole
env ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=localhost:2379 --cert tls.pem --key tls.key --cacert ca.pem auth enable
```

Etcd documentation for Authentication says, that if client uses TLS certificate then CN is taken from that certificate and used as etcd `user`. My certificate `tls.pem` has `CN=myuser` and therefore:

```
env ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=localhost:2379 --cert tls.pem --key tls.key --cacert ca.pem put /events/1 value
```

Will result in `permission denied`, which is correct, since only `read` permission is given for `myuser`. However the documentation also says, that if `--user` option is used along with TLS certificates, then that `--user` will have priority over `CN`. Which means, that if I run:

```
env ETCDCTL_API=3 etcdctl --endpoints=localhost:2379 --cert tls.pem --key tls.key --cacert ca.pem --user=root:mypass put /events/1 value
```

Then `root` user should be used to perform that operation, which I expect it to result in `OK`, however it doesn't happen, and instead I got the same stuff - `permission denied`. What can cause that problem? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot help with `--user` issue, i.e why it doesn't work, however, why can't you use following approach. You use TLS auth, that's good, but why don't you create `master.clientv3` and `myuserN.clientv3`, where Master is kinda master TLS certificate with `CN=master` and other TLS certificates follow the pattern of `CN=myuserN`, where `N=0,1,2,...`. Then you grant `root` role to the `master` user and `myrole` to all `myuserN`.

In such case you could use master certificate to fully control etcd and other certificates with `myrole` role, i.e having only `read` permission on `/events/1` key.

Following that idea, you can basically create any other `permissions` and having one `master` client to control everything in etcd. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Hmm, well it is interesting why still `--user` doesn't work, but your proposed one, indeed, works! Accepting